# Проблема после установки GitLab

Tags: git, debian, gitlab

Установил GitLab по инструкции с официального сайта. После установки в файле ***/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*** прописал такое

```
external_url 'http://w4u.com.ua:7070'
```

но по этому адресу ничего не открывается. Что надо сделать еще?

Система - Debian 8

Comment: как минимум перезагрузить сервисы

Comment: делал командой ***sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure*** и ***sudo gitlab-ctl restart***

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -tunlp` и посмотреть вообще занял ли gitlab этот порт.
Знает ли система о том какой ip адрес у w4u.com.ua, и что этот ip адрес локальный, то есть присвоен какой либо сетевой карточке?

Comment: по ходу нет, потому что команда ***service gitlab-ctl status*** выдала ***gitlab-ctl.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)***

Comment: сори, я тормознул. gitlab запущен, но тут ***netstat -tunlp*** его не видно

Comment: gitlab-ctl.service Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory) - он вам говорит что такого сервиса не существует.

Comment: я не верно вводил команду. такой командой его не запустить, но я запустил другой